# Ruby on Rails: Keep check boxes selected after search

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my RoR application I have a form whereby users can search for their contacts by first name and select the ones that they want to send an email to. My problem is that after searching for say "Tom", and selecting the checkbox for "Tom", if they then reset the search to display all check boxes "Tom" is no longer selected.

Can someone please tell me how this can be sorted?

The code in the view is:

```
<div class="panel-body">
    <%= form_tag '/emails/contact_search', :method => 'get' do %>
      <p>
        <%= text_field_tag :search_string, params[:search_string], :placeholder => "Search by firstname" %>
        <%= submit_tag "Search" %>
      </p>
    <% end %>
    <%= form_for(@email) do |f| %>
        <fieldset>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>From Email Address</label></br>
                <% @useraccounts.each do |useraccount| %>
                    <%= f.radio_button :account_id, useraccount.account_id, :checked => false %>
                    <%= f.label :account_id, useraccount.account.email, :value => "true"  %><br>
                <% end %>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Contacts</label></br>
                <%= f.collection_check_boxes :contact_ids, @contacts, :id, :fullname, checked: @selected_contact_ids %>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Groups</label></br>
                <%= f.collection_check_boxes :group_ids, Group.where(user_id: session[:user_id]), :id, :name ,{ prompt: "name" } %>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Attachment</label>
                <%= f.file_field :attachment, :size => 42 %><br>
            </div>
            <div class="actions">
                <%= f.submit "Continue", {:class => 'btn btn-primary '} %>
                <%= render "/error_messages", :message_header => "Cannot save: ", :target => @email %>  
            </div></br>

        </fieldset> 
    <% end %>
</div>
```

The controller code for the search is:

```
 def contact_search
    @email = Email.new(session[:email_params])
    @email.current_step == session[:email_step]
    @useraccounts = Useraccount.where(user_id: session[:user_id])
    @contacts = Contact.contact_search(params[:search_string])
    if @contacts.empty?
        flash[:notice] = "There are no emails with that subject"
        @contacts = Contact.all
    end
    render :action => "new"
 end
private
def email_params
    params.require(:email).permit(:subject, :message, :account_id, { contact_ids: [] }, { group_ids: [] }, :attachment)
end
```

And in the model:

```
def self.contact_search(search_string)
    self.where("firstname LIKE ?", search_string)
end
```

I cannot work out how to keep a checkbox selected after a  user then searches for something else or resets the search, can someone please shed some light on how this can be achieved?

Comment: Please don't tag the question with just anything, this is purely a Rails issue, not a Ruby one.

Comment: I am using Ruby on Rails 4 and the question is regarding check boxes, I feel those tags are relevant.

Comment: No, you tagged both Ruby and Rails3, which are irrelevant. This is not an issue with Rails4, just with the method in question.

Comment: I am using tags that will categorise my question with other, similar questions. There are many other questions on Stack Overflow that use such tags though the question regards a specific method; meaning that tagging this question as such will categorise it in line with other questions. I will leave it as is to end the argument, I am more concerned with solving the problem.

Comment: Did you manage to get it to work? I'm working on something similar and need to know any solution

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be one of those obscure and badly documented features of Rails. What has to be done is pass an array if ids to be checked into the `checked` parameter

```
= f.collection_check_boxes :contact_ids, @contacts, :id, :fullname, checked: @selected_contact_ids
```

and then check boxes with items of `id` 1, 2 and 3 will be checked. You will need to pass this array obviously from the controller somehow. E.g.

```
@selected_contact_ids = email_params.fetch(:contact_ids, [])
```

Comment: Thanks :) Unfortunately this still does not work as after selecting a checkbox and searching again, the checkbox is no longer selected

Comment: What is the params that are posted from the form? Maybe you just need to tweak the `params.fetch(` part to get the correct values. I tested this myself, so the code works, you just need to tweak it to your case.

Comment: I have added the `email_params` that are included in the controller. I have also added the `@selected_contact_ids = params.fetch(:contact_ids, [])` just above the `render :action => "new"` in the `contact_search` method.

Comment: Yeah, that is what I mean, then you will have to do `email_params.fetch(:contact_ids, [])`

Comment: Thanks, I shouldn't have missed that! This, however, causes the error `param is missing or the value is empty: email` when selecting a checkbox and then searching.

Comment: What is the html name of the generated check boxes?

Comment: The html for the generated check boxes is: `<input type="checkbox" value="11" name="email[contact_ids][]" id="email_contact_ids_11" /><label for="email_contact_ids_11">Tom Jones</label>`.

Note - the search is in a `form_tag` whereas the form to create a new email is in `form_for` - I will update the question to show this.

Comment: Ok, then `email_params.fetch(:contact_ids, [])` should work.

Comment: But for some reason this isn't working, is it because of the two different forms?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136283/discussion-between-iceman-and-ben-smith).